# error: [ExtendedImageProvider.cacheRawData] to true

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using this
[extended_Image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image) to crop images from then Save the raw file to phone, get the raw data and push it to firebase storage. but i keep getting this error.

> Unhandled Exception:
> 'package:extended_image_library/src/extended_image_provider.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 34 pos 12: 'cacheRawData': you should set
> [ExtendedImageProvider.cacheRawData] to true, if you want to get
> rawImageData from provider.

which i did not understand.
here is my code

```
Future<void> crop([bool test = false]) async {
    final ExtendedImageEditorState state = editorKey.currentState;
    final Rect rect = state.getCropRect();
    final EditActionDetails action = state.editAction;
    final double radian = action.rotateAngle;

    final bool flipHorizontal = action.flipY;
    final bool flipVertical = action.flipX;
    final Uint8List img = state.rawImageData;

    final option = ImageEditorOption();

    option.addOption(ClipOption.fromRect(rect));
    option.addOption(
        FlipOption(horizontal: flipHorizontal, vertical: flipVertical));
    if (action.hasRotateAngle) {
      option.addOption(RotateOption(radian.toInt()));
    }

    option.addOption(ColorOption.saturation(sat));
    option.addOption(ColorOption.brightness(bright + 1));
    option.addOption(ColorOption.contrast(con));

    option.outputFormat = const OutputFormat.jpeg(100);

    print(const JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(option.toJson()));

    final DateTime start = DateTime.now();
    final Uint8List result = await ImageEditor.editImage(
      image: img,
      imageEditorOption: option,
    );

    print('result.length = ${result?.length}');

    final Duration diff = DateTime.now().difference(start);
    image?.writeAsBytesSync(result);
    print('image_editor time : $diff');
    //--here is the uploading url--
    final imageUrl = await uploadingFile(uploadFile: image);
    // storing the url to console
    firestore
        .collection('Image')
        .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid)
        .collection('Photos')
        .doc()
        .set({
      'picture': imageUrl,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ExtendedExactAssetImageProvider(widget.params['path'],cacheRawData: true)
```

Comment: i forgot to answer this, is already solved... anyways i will mark your answer

Comment: Please provide the solution